# Analyzing the convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, q-series

I have a series like this:$$\sum_{n=0}^∞\left(\frac{λδ_t}2\right)^n\frac1{n!}\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n-j}C_n^j\exp\left(\frac{(n-2j)^2}{2δ^2}+\frac{(n-2j)γ}δ\right),$$where $C_n^j$ is the binominal coefficient, and $δ_t$ is the volatility of the GARCH model.

I tried to estimate the series $\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n-j}C_n^j\exp\left(\frac{(n-2j)^2}{2\delta^2}+\frac{(n-2j)\gamma}{\delta}\right)$ like this:
$$\exp\left(\frac{(n-2j)^2}{2\delta^2}+\frac{(n-2j)\gamma}{\delta}\right)\le \exp\left(\frac{n^2}{2\delta^2}+\frac{(n-j)\gamma}{\delta}\right),$$
so
$$\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n-j}C_n^j\exp\left(\frac{(n-2j)^2}{2\delta^2}+\frac{(n-2j)\gamma}{\delta}\right)\le \sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n-j}C_n^j\exp\left(\frac{n^2}{2\delta^2}+\frac{(n-j)\gamma}{\delta}\right)\\
=(-1)^n\exp\left(\frac{n^2}{2\delta^2}\right)\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{j}C_n^j\exp\left(\frac{(n-j)\gamma}{\delta}\right)=(-1)^n\exp\left(\frac{n^2}{2\delta^2}\right)(e^{\gamma/\delta}-1),$$
but since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n!}\exp\left(\dfrac{n^2}{2\delta^2}\right)=\infty$ the series does not converge.

Maybe there may be another upper bound which proves its convergence? Because the lower rude estimation $\exp\left(\dfrac{(n-2j)^2}{2\delta^2}+\dfrac{(n-2j)\gamma}{\delta}\right)\geqslant1$ gives a sum about $1$.

Comment: The lower bound you mention isn't reliable, because the terms in the inner sum have alternating signs.

Comment: it's reliable, for example, if you take: $\frac{d}{dj}(\frac{(n-2j)^2}{2\delta^2}+\frac{(n-2j)\gamma}{\delta})=0  \xrightarrow{} j_{min}=\frac{n+\gamma\delta}{2}$ , so $e^{\frac{(n-2j)^2}{2\delta^2}+\frac{(n-2j)\gamma}{\delta}}\geqslant e^{-\frac{\gamma^2}{2}}$, and $e^{-\frac{\gamma^2}{2}}\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^jC^j_n=0\le \sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^jC^j_ne^{\frac{(n-2j)^2}{2\delta^2}+\frac{(n-2j)\gamma}{\delta}}$

Comment: here i used Binomial theorem